# inserting data using mysql Connector in python

Tags: python, mysql, insert, mysql-connector

i've faced an wired problem that's when i'am about to insert data into my database it's not inserting and not failing (throwing exception)  either ! ,, when data is duplicated or wrong table provided it's throws exceptions  !!

here's my code !

```
from mysql import connector
con = connector.Connect(user='root',password='root',database='test',host='localhost')
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("""insert into user values ('userName', 'passWord')""")
```

the database `test` include only one table which is `users` and include 3 fields which is `id` and `username` and `password` , username is unique and id is A_I

**note**
i've used this query also ! :

> """insert into user (`username`,`password`) values ('userName',
>   'passWord');"""

and tried so many ways , but nothing happend (not inserted and no exceptions throwed either !)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
from mysql import connector
con = connector.Connect(user='root',password='root',database='test',host='localhost')
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("""insert into user values ('userName', 'passWord')""")
**con.commit()**
con.close()
```

You probably forget to use con.commit, to commit your changes to database.

*Don't use con.commit() for for each INSERT/UPDATE operation, use it for group of operations, that logical combines by SQL rules*

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're probably forgetting to commit your changes.