# google analytics api: push data stored in to a variable into maria db

Tags: api, google-analytics, mariadb

i have a quick question
this is my python code to retrieve data from google analtycs api. 
it works just fine. 
i would like now to push the result into maria database running on my local machine. i built alrady the scheme and the table in mysql. i was able to establish the connection with maria db. Can you show me how to push the data stored in to the variable "df" into the database?

import google2pandas
from google2pandas import *
conn = GoogleAnalyticsQuery(secrets='C:/Users/blabla/OneDrive/MyFiles/Documents/analysis/ga-creds/ga-credsclient_secrets.json', token_file_name='C:/Users/l.longo/OneDrive/MyFiles/Documents/analysis//ga-creds/analytics.dat')
query = {\
  'ids' : 'ga:23185143',
  'metrics' : 'pageviews',
  'dimensions' : ['date', 'pagePath'],
  'start_date' : '8daysAgo'
}

df, metadata = conn.execute_query(**query)
print(df)
import mysql.connector as mariadb
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='xxxxx', database='xxxxxx')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

here you have the results i get from analytics api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w24H9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INSERT` statement over your mysql connection.
Check this question
[Inserting Data using MySql Connector in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013597/inserting-data-using-mysql-connector-in-python)

Comment: i see. thanx but how i can insert the data stored in to df variable of my code into the db?

Comment: You should create a table first, matching the fields of your df variable, after that, loop then df variable creating an insert statement.